# How to show and hide header when user click anywhere in page?

Tags: jquery-mobile

can you please tell me How to show and hide header when user click anywhere in page?
I think i  need to use **toggle** class and **('.header').show('slow');** or hide .i don't know how to use that?
http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/YcxtS/

```
<div  data-role="header">

    <h1>Add Images</h1>

</div>
```

This is basis header .But I need to implement header having multiple images scrolling horizontally .
how to scroll images horizontally in jquery mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add these attributes to your header: **`data-position="fixed"`** and **`data-fullscreen="true"`**.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/uTpH4/

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true">
                <h1>Index page</h1>
                <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="edit">Next</a>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">

            </div>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: one More issue is that i need to add scrolling images on header .swap images .can i use iscroller in that?